# DeserializerContext.readValue() throws end-of-input exception

Tags: json, kotlin, jackson, jackson-databind

I have an issue with my code and somehow this code below throws a MismatchedInputException with an end-of-input error:

**JSON**

```
{
  "users": {
    "user": {
      "name": "TestUser",
      "age": 32,
      "description": "abc123"
    }
  }
}
```

**UserWrapper.kt** (should be mapped to "users" element in JSON)

```
package p2

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize

@JsonDeserialize(using = UserWrapperDeserializer::class)
class UserWrapper(val user: User?)
```

**User.kt** (should be mapped to "user" element in JSON)

```
package p2

class User(val name: String, val age: Int, val special: String)
```

**UserWrapperDeserializer.kt**

```
package p2

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode

class UserWrapperDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<UserWrapper>() {

    override fun deserialize(p: JsonParser?, ctxt: DeserializationContext?): UserWrapper? {
        val userNode = p?.codec?.readTree<JsonNode>(p)?.get("user")
        return UserWrapper(ctxt?.readValue(userNode?.traverse(p.codec), User::class.java))
        //Line above throws MismatchedInputException: Unexpected end-of-input
    }

}
```

Is there a reason why `DeserializationContext.readValue()` doesn't work?

Comment: My humble guess would be: You read in the json and try to `get("user")` but the json you provide here has a `"users"` root node and therefore is unable to find the node `"user"`. Besides that: Do you have a specific need to have a `user` inside a `users` node? You could reduce the complexity if you could get rid of this extra layer

Comment: @T8xi Thanks for the tip! I would really love to reduce the complexity and this format is really nonsense imo but it’s an api response so I unfortunately can’t change it...

Comment: Ok, then you could create a `Users` object which contains a (or multiple) `User` object and let the jackson parser do the job for you. Your method would then fully rely on the jackson build in binding mechanisms. Then you would not need to read in the root node and let the deserializer do its job.

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55855414/custom-jackson-deserialization-getting-com-fasterxml-jackson-databind-exc-mism?